# How do I subclass/override Ember.Logger?

Tags: ember.js

I am implementing remote logging ability in my Ember app, where I want to push everything that gets sent to the log console to a remote logging service (e.g. Loggly).

I believe that what I need to do is override `Ember.Logger`'s methods to redirect log output to the remote logging service, but I can't figure out how to do that.

The [documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Logger.html) for `Ember.Logger` simply states:

> Override this to provide more robust logging functionality.

1. How do I "override this"? I've tried doing `Ember.Logger.reopenClass()` and it complains with `Ember.Logger.reopenClass is not a function`.
2. Where would I do this? In an initializer? In a service? Other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Ember.Logger` is not an Ember class. It's just an object with some methods on it.

You can override it by something like

```
Ember.Logger.log = function(...
```

You can put this wherever you want. I might put it at the top of `app.js`.

Comment: Ah well. Hopefully one day I'll wrap my head around all the ways "classes" and "objects" can be defined in Javascript. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

Expanding upon and updating @user663031 response...

As of Nov 2017, the status of `Ember.Logger` is up in the air. It was not included in [Ember's module API](https://github.com/emberjs/rfcs/pull/176#issuecomment-272566327), and there isn't yet an RFC for the future.

It is possible use a debug utility directly, e.g. [ember-debug-logger](https://github.com/salsify/ember-debug-logger/issues/7), and extend those prototypes separate from `Ember.Logger`.

However, I opted to overwrite `Ember.Logger` directly because it allows me to include any logging tool that I like (as opposed to debug util) without having to modify the log statements scattered throughout the code.

As I use bunyan on the backend, opted to log with [browser-bunyan](https://github.com/philmander/browser-bunyan), which incidentally has the same `info`, `warn`, `error` as `Ember.Logger`.

YMMV, but this is the minimal example that worked for me...

[image]

```
// app/app.js
import LOG from './logger-bunyan';
if (config.APP.LOG_BUNYAN) {
    Ember.Logger = LOG;
}

// app/logger-bunyan.js
import bunyan from 'npm:browser-bunyan';

const LOG = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'emberApplication',
});

export default LOG;

// config/environment.js
if (environment === 'development') {
    ENV.APP.LOG_BUNYAN = true;
}

// app/component/WhereIWantToLog.js
Logger.warn('bunyan logged warning message')
```